# Parallel Process to Wake-up and Send Email Alert 72 Hours Before Scheduled Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, scheduled-tasks

I have an application written in ASP.NET MVC 2 that stores the date and time of a user's scheduled event in an MSSQL database.  I need the application to send an email alert to the user 72 hours before the stored event occurs without any manual intervention.

What is the best way to implement this parallel process (I already have the email code)?

Comment: what's parallel about this process?

Comment: The email alerts are being sent in parallel to the other application functions.

Comment: that's an unorthodox use of the word. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the events stored in a database, I would create a Windows Service which ran independently of the asp.net application, which regularly polled the database looking for work to be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server then I would probably go with the Windows Service (like [The Evil Greebo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430203/parallel-process-to-wake-up-and-send-email-alert-72-hours-before-scheduled-event/6430245#6430245)).

But assuming you don't, I would create a class, perhaps similar to the one below, which you can use/inherit from.  Instantiate this class during the "Application_start" event in global.asax and save a copy of it in the cache.  Put your logic in the "ExecuteProcess" method.  Your logic would probably look something like (pseudo code):

```
while(true) 
   check for events that need to have notifications sent

   send any needed notifications

   wait x seconds and repeate

loop
```

Make sure you have a field in your MSSQL database table for tracking whether a notification has been sent.

Basic base class:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public MustInherit Class LongRunningProcess
    Public ReadOnly Property Running() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Running
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Success() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Success
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Exception() As Exception
        Get
            Return _Exception
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property StartTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return _StartTime
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property EndTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return _EndTime
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Args() As Object
        Get
            Return _Args
        End Get
    End Property


    Protected _Running As Boolean = False
    Protected _Success As Boolean = False
    Protected _Exception As Exception = Nothing
    Protected _StartTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Protected _EndTime As DateTime = DateTime.MinValue
    Protected _Args() As Object = Nothing
    Protected WithEvents _Thread As Thread

    Private _locker As New Object()

    Public Sub Execute(ByVal Arguments As Object)
        SyncLock (_locker)
            'if the process is not running, then...'
            If Not _Running Then
                'Set running to true'
                _Running = True
                'Set start time to now'
                _StartTime = DateTime.Now
                'set arguments'
                _Args = Arguments
                'Prepare to process in a new thread'
                _Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf ExecuteProcess))

                'Start the thread'
                _Thread.Start()
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Protected MustOverride Sub ExecuteProcess()
End Class
```

The Args property gives you access from within "ExecuteProcess" to any arguments/variables you might need.

Comment: I do not have control over the server so I'll re-write your solution in C# and give it a try - Thanks!